# How to use tikz-nodes to place and display external images?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, includegraphics

In `tikz` placing labels via `\nodes` is quite convenient and used all the time. How to display and position external images instead of text?

Comment: you can use `\includegraphics` anywhere where you can use text

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Before you can run this example, copy 3 images to the same directory as the .tex file, and rename them img-1.X, img-2.X and img-3.X, where `X` denotes a graphics format like `png`, `jpg` etc.

Place and draw a node as usual and put `\includegraphics[height=1cm]{img-1}` inside the nodes braces where you would put text.

If you want to connect nodes later, name them. Draw connections as usual, e.g. by using the `\graph` statement.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}% needed for the \graph - statement


% DO BEFOREHAND: copy and rename 3 images img-1 to img-3 to the same directory
\begin{document}

\tikz {
    % --- that's all you need to place and show an image by a node ---
    \node [draw=red] at (0,4)       {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{img-1}};
    
    % --- to connect nodes it's practical to name the nodes ---
    \node (brd) [draw] at (0,0)     {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img-1}};
    \node (stk) [draw] at (5,0)     {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img-3}};
    \node (set) [draw] at (3.5, 3.5)    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img-2}};

    % --- let the sticks point towards two image-nodes ---
    \graph {
        (stk) -> [blue] {(brd), (set)}% reference aboves nodes by paranthesis ()
    };
}

\end{document}
```

Inspired by David's comment "*you can use `\includegraphics` anywhere where you can use text*" it's also possible, to attach a sloped image to a connecting line:

[image: sloped image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}% needed for the \graph - statement


% DO BEFOREHAND: copy and rename 3 images img-1 to img-3 to the same directory
\begin{document}

\tikz {
    
    % --- to connect nodes it's practical to name the nodes ---
    \node (brd) [draw] at (0,0)     {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img-3}};
    \node (set) [draw] at (3.5, 3.5)    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img-2}};


    % --- connecting with a sloped text above ----
    \draw (brd) -- node [sloped, above] {\small{label}} (set);
    
    % --- connecting, with sloped image below and a curved connector ---
    \draw [->] (brd) to [out=-30 , in=-100] 
        node [sloped, below] {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{img-1}} (set);
}

\end{document}
```

Because beginners in `tikz` sometimes have trouble, here's David's advice applied in reverse, if you like: just classical placement and styling of text without using any image.

The codes structure is copied from the last example, introducing short hand notation for text, providing some styling, placing two text-nodes, providing two connectors with text-labels.

Your take-away: It's still the same structure in tikz, only the content handled change (from images to text).

[image: same code structure, with text rather than images]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}% needed for the \graph - statement

% --- "text variables" to keep code cleaner -----------------
\def\stks{sticks}
\def\drst{Drummers set shown from Clyde Stubblefield and Yogi Horton}
\def\brd{drumset board}

\begin{document}

\tikz [dst/.style={text width=2cm, node font=\tiny},% styling the drums text
       lbls/.style={node font=\small, color=blue}, sloped]% styling the label texts
    {
    
    % --- to connect by graphs it's practical to name the nodes ---
    \node (stk) [draw]      at (0,0)        {\stks};% sticks, lower left
    \node (set) [draw, dst] at (3.5, 3.5)   {\drst};% upper right, styled


    % --- connecting with a sloped and styled text above ----
    \draw (stk) -- node [above, lbls] {label-text} (set);
    
    % --- connecting, with sloped and styled text below and a curved connector ---
    \draw [->] (stk) to [out=-30 , in=-100]% flexing the line
        node [below, lbls] {\brd} (set);
}

\end{document}
```