# Blockchain Network using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I know that this is not a specific problem, but I'm looking for a library that has icons that I can directly use to draw how blockchain network works by using Latex. Is there any such library or package that I can use.

Here is the way it should look like

https://pipeandpiper.co.uk/2021/08/16/what-is-cryptocurrency/

[image]

Comment: Please provide some visual hints (link, picture, or sketch) for how the icons in blockchain network look like.

Comment: I did upload a link

Comment: What you can do more or less right away is finding free grpahics, e.g. here https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+icons (pointing e.g. here https://icons8.com/icons/set/blockchain) , and place them by nodes, like described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647400/how-to-use-tikz-nodes-to-place-and-display-external-images .

Comment: The simple way is to include showed image with `\includegraphics`. For drawing with `tikz` you first should show, what you try so far and where you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here’s one way to achieve what you want. Purpose is to line out a process of creating such a library for yourself, with some remaining room for improvement.

The basic idea is: using `\pic` elements, which describe one component (”icon”). See ch. 18 in the `pgf-manual` for details.

To do so we need a good guess about the `\pic`-s dimensions. So in the screenshot I singled out 2, and a compound formed by them. The black rectangles mimick a frame, with pixel coordinates; blue indicate width and height. So a frame of 10cm * 5cm (or similar) may be reasonable.

[image: Screenshot of two relevant "icons"]

The code is one `\tikz [] {}` statement, which starts with some `styles`, describes 3 simple `\pic`-s and a compound one. Finally these are placed along a `\path` and shown.

The simple `\pics` comprise `monitor`, `cube` and `wave`. You certainly can improve some aspects here, if you want, like replacing my guessed coordinates by more reasonable ones.

The compound `\pic` called `waveCube` is made from a cube, 4 waves and monitors, to obtain something like the faded 3rd image in aboves screenshot.

As you can see, there is left room for improvement. E.g. the `waveCube` doesn’t scale, which is probably due to using absolute coordinates inside. // You can certainly use the `\tikzset` statement and move all styles and pics there.

[image: All \pic-s shown]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 


\begin{document}

\tikz [
    % --- some styles ------------
    dbl/.style={thick, double distance=5pt, rounded corners},
    wv/.style={start angle=0, end angle=70},
    wvr/.style={rotate=10, gray, very thick},
    %
    % --- simple pics -----------------
    monitor/.pic={
        \draw [dbl]
            (1, 0.6) rectangle (9, 5);% monitor
        \draw (0, 0.2) rectangle (10, 0.5);% kbd
        \draw (0.2, 0) rectangle (9.8, 0.2);
        },
    cube/.pic={
        \draw [dbl] (1.0, 1) -- (2.5, 0.5) -- 
                    (2.5, 3) -- (1.0, 3.5) -- cycle;
        \draw [dbl] (1.0, 3.5) -- (2.5, 3) -- 
                    (3.8, 3.6) -- (2.5, 4.2) -- cycle;
        \draw [dbl] (2.5, 3) -- (3.8, 3.6) -- 
                    (3.8, 1.3) -- (2.5, 0.5) -- cycle;
    },
    wave/.pic={
        \draw [wvr] (1,0)   arc[wv, radius=1cm];
        \draw [wvr] (0.7,0) arc[wv, radius=0.7cm];
        \draw [wvr] (0.4,0) arc[wv, radius=0.4cm];
    },
    %
    % --- compund pics -----------------
    waveCube/.pic={
        \draw pic  [scale=0.4]  at (0,0) {cube}
              pic               at (2,2) {wave}
              pic [rotate=90]   at (0,2) {wave}
              pic [rotate=270]  at (2,0) {wave}
              pic [rotate=180]  at (0,0) {wave}       
              %
              pic [scale=0.2]   at (3.5,-1) {monitor}
              pic [scale=0.2]   at (3.5, 2) {monitor}
              pic [scale=0.2]   at (-3.5,-1) {monitor}
              pic [scale=0.2]   at (-3.5, 2) {monitor}
              ;
    }
     ]
     % --- now the drawing ----------
     {
        \path (1,1)
        -- (10,0) pic           {monitor}% lower right
        -- (5,5)  pic [scale=1] {cube}% middle
        -- (0,0)  pic           {wave}% lower left
        -- (0,10) pic           {waveCube}% upper left
        -- (15, 8) pic [scale=0.8] {waveCube}% upper right
        ;
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TikZ library for LaTeX to create illustrations for a blockchain network. TikZ is a powerful graphics library that can be used to create a wide variety of diagrams and illustrations, including those for a blockchain network. With TikZ, you can create detailed illustrations with customized shapes, labels, and arrows, making it an ideal choice for technical illustrations.

Here's an example of how you could use TikZ to create a simple illustration of a blockchain network in LaTeX:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle, draw] (A) {A};
\node[shape=circle, draw, right of=A] (B) {B};
\node[shape=circle, draw, right of=B] (C) {C};
\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code creates a simple illustration of three nodes in a line connected by arrows to represent a blockchain network. You can customize the appearance of the nodes, arrows, and other elements to create more complex illustrations.

There are also many examples and tutorials available online that show how to use TikZ to create illustrations for blockchain networks and other technical illustrations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome. // Nice. Can you please add a screenshot of the codes result to your post? Thanks