# Tikz IOT- network

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, cloud, tikzpeople

I want to paint a IOT network, in Tikz. On the left side I need a television, two Persons,
In the middle i want a speaker with tikz and on the right side i need symbols (A door cloud, a phone).

I found the wonderful package people. Is there a similar package for tikz to draw ?
Here is my code so far.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
      \node[alice,minimum size=1cm] (A) {};
      \node[bob,right=1cm of A,minimum size=1cm,mirrored] (B) {};
      \draw (A) (B); %node[draw,circle, fill=white, text width=1cm, align=center] edge[->] {} (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Iot Network]
Best

Comment: There is the `tikzpeople` package. Or do you already know this? I don't quite understand what you are looking for. Also, please provide a full compilable example.

Comment: Yeah, i am using it! But the monitor, which is in the node, must contain a name! Like bob, i need just a monitor on the right!

Comment: You are right, i am sorry to not attach a example! This is basically what I want in the tikz picture!

Comment: Hm, nobody can use your code snippet ... as the important ingredients are missing. // It's not difficult to create the missing ones: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647646/245790

Comment: If you need some specific icons, you can always use some icon set from whatever source and include the single icons using `\includegraphics` (via the `graphicx` package). This might be easier to draw the icons from scratch ... (which you could also do, of course)