# How can I make a Tikz picture into a node?

Tags: nodes

I am trying to produce a mechanics worksheet to teach Newtons 2 Law!
I want an engine pulling trucks.  I have used savebox to save the tikz image of the engine and truck and hoped i could store as a named node to be able to 'join' the objects.
When I try to give the node a name by inserting eg(A) after the node I get an error " No shape named A is known". This means i can't join the objects.
All ideas welcome!
Below is my MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\Truck
\sbox\Truck{\begin{tikzpicture}
        %   \draw (0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw [fill=gray!20] (1.75,0.1) rectangle  (4.75,0.75);
        \draw [fill=gray] (2,0.15) circle (0.15) (2.5,0.15) circle (0.15) (4,0.15) circle (0.15) (4.5,0.15) circle (0.15);
        
        
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newsavebox\Engine
\sbox\Engine{\begin{tikzpicture}
        %   \draw (0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw [fill=gray!20] (0,0.2) --(3.4,0.2)--(3.4,2)--(2.4,2)--(2.3,1.4)--(0,1.4)--(0,0.2);  
        \draw [fill=gray!80] (0.8,0.4) circle (0.4) (1.7,0.4) circle (0.4) (2.6,0.4) circle (0.4) ;
        \draw [fill=gray!50] (0.4,1) rectangle (2,1.2);
        \draw [fill=gray!5] (2.5,1) rectangle (3.2,1.7);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={transform shape},
        truck/.style={node contents=\usebox{\Truck}},
        engine/.style={node contents=\usebox{\Engine}}
        ]
        \draw (0,0) node[truck,above](A)--(4,0) node[truck,above]--(8,0) node[ above,engine];

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try the concepts given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647401/245790

Comment: Thank you. I had seen this but since i was creating the object in tikz it seemed counter intuitive to screen shot it and then save it as a picture to use.  I felt there must be a more efficient method!

Comment: The message is: put inside a node what you put inside Latex ...

Comment: If you use `node contents` you can't have anything after the `]` that closes the options that amongst other sets the `node` contents. The node name or the `at (…)` needs to come before, i.e. `node (A) [truck, above]` or needs to be part of the options, e.g. `node[truck, above, name=A]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple solution using `positioning`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% added <<<<<<<<<<

\newsavebox\Truck
\sbox\Truck{\begin{tikzpicture}
        %   \draw (0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw [fill=gray!20] (1.75,0.1) rectangle  (4.75,0.75);
        \draw [fill=gray] (2,0.15) circle (0.15) (2.5,0.15) circle (0.15) (4,0.15) circle (0.15) (4.5,0.15) circle (0.15);      
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newsavebox\Engine
\sbox\Engine{\begin{tikzpicture}
        %   \draw (0,0)--(10,0);
        \draw [fill=gray!20] (0,0.2) --(3.4,0.2)--(3.4,2)--(2.4,2)--(2.3,1.4)--(0,1.4)--(0,0.2);  
        \draw [fill=gray!80] (0.8,0.4) circle (0.4) (1.7,0.4) circle (0.4) (2.6,0.4) circle (0.4) ;
        \draw [fill=gray!50] (0.4,1) rectangle (2,1.2);
        \draw [fill=gray!5] (2.5,1) rectangle (3.2,1.7);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt](E){\usebox{\Engine}};
        \node(T)[right= 2cm of E.south east, anchor = south west,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\Truck}};   
        \draw  (T.west)-- (T-|E.east);          
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right. I missed the positioning aspect in my answer. My answer was actually rather a test for myself to check how this `path picture` option works, I rarely use it. =)

Answer (score 6):

Note that every node needs a (probably empty) label text. So, you always should place a pair of curly braces after every `\node` (or `node`) macro.

Now, if you really want to place drawings inside nodes, what you can do is to use `pic`s in combination with `path picture`.

Actually, it might be easier to just use the `pic`s without placing them inside nodes. It is very easy to just place them somewhere using just `\pic at (0,0) {truck};` for example. But since I don't know what your aim is eventually, I post this solution:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    truck/.pic={
        \draw[fill=gray!20] 
            (-1.5,0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.75);
        \draw[fill=gray] 
            (-1.25,0.15) circle[radius=0.15] 
            (-0.75,0.15) circle[radius=0.15] 
            (0.75,0.15) circle[radius=0.15] 
            (1.25,0.15) circle[radius=0.15];
    },
    engine/.pic={
        \draw[fill=gray!20] 
            (-1.7,0.2) -- (1.7,0.2) -- (1.7,2) -- (0.7,2) 
                -- (0.6,1.4) -- (-1.7,1.4) -- (-1.7,0.2);  
        \draw[fill=gray!80] 
            (-0.9,0.4) circle[radius=0.4] 
            (0,0.4) circle[radius=0.4] 
            (0.9,0.4) circle[radius=0.4];
        \draw[fill=gray!50] 
            (-1.3,1) rectangle (0.3,1.2);
        \draw[fill=gray!5] 
            (0.8,1) rectangle (1.5,1.7);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        truck/.style={
            minimum width={3cm+0.4pt},
            minimum height={2cm+0.4pt},
            path picture={
                \pic at ([yshift=0.2pt]path picture bounding box.south) {truck};
            },
            yshift=0.67cm
        },
        engine/.style={
            minimum width={3.4cm+0.4pt},
            minimum height={2cm+0.4pt},
            path picture={
                \pic at ([yshift=0.2pt]path picture bounding box.south) {engine};
            },
            yshift=0.67cm
        },
    ]

    \draw 
        (0,0) node[engine, fill=cyan!10] {} 
            -- (4,0) node[truck, fill=cyan!10] {} 
            -- (8,0) node[truck, fill=cyan!10] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation:

First I converted your drawings of the truck and the engine to `pic`s. This is very simple since it is actually just the code you already hat. I only shifted the drawings a bit to the left, so that they are horizontally centered at *y* = 0. Both drawings sit on the same baseline (at *x* = 0).

Then, I used the `path picture` option to create styles for the nodes where I essentially just place the relevant `pic` so that it becomes the background of the node. It is important here to correctly set the width and height of the node: It should be as wide and as high as the pic plus half of the line width, because otherwise the lines will be clipped at the borders of the node. I aligned the `path picture`s relative to the bottom of the relevant node using `path picture bounding box.south`.

I finally shifted the nodes a bit, so that they sit at a reasonable height relative to the connecting line. I shaded the background of the nodes just to make them visible. You may want to remove this shading.

---

As stated above, a much simpler approach is to only use `pic`s and use the ability to add prefixable coordinates to them (somewhat similar to anchors):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    truck/.pic={
        \draw[fill=gray!20] 
            (-1.5,0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.75);
        \draw[fill=gray] 
            (-1.25,0.15) circle[radius=0.15] 
            (-0.75,0.15) circle[radius=0.15] 
            (0.75,0.15) circle[radius=0.15] 
            (1.25,0.15) circle[radius=0.15];
        \coordinate (-front) at (-1.5,0.25);
        \coordinate (-back) at (1.5,0.25);
    },
    engine/.pic={
        \draw[fill=gray!20] 
            (-1.7,0.2) -- (1.7,0.2) -- (1.7,2) -- (0.7,2) 
                -- (0.6,1.4) -- (-1.7,1.4) -- (-1.7,0.2);  
        \draw[fill=gray!80] 
            (-0.9,0.4) circle[radius=0.4] 
            (0,0.4) circle[radius=0.4] 
            (0.9,0.4) circle[radius=0.4];
        \draw[fill=gray!50] 
            (-1.3,1) rectangle (0.3,1.2);
        \draw[fill=gray!5] 
            (0.8,1) rectangle (1.5,1.7);
        \coordinate (-front) at (-1.7,0.25);
        \coordinate (-back) at (1.7,0.25);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic (A) at (0,0) {engine};
    \pic (B) at (3.5,0) {truck};
    \pic (C) at (7,0) {truck};

    \draw 
        (A-back) -- (B-front)
        (B-back) -- (C-front);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great - just what I wanted.  I had tried pics but couldn't link them. I wasn't aware of the 'prefixable coordinates' which clearly let me join the separate parts.

Comment: @ToyBoy It is probably also possible to directly use a `path picture` but somehow, it seems difficult to align it inside the node. It is easier to align a `pic` inside a `path picture`. As for the pure `pic` solution: It is not as easy to position `pic`s relative to each other as it is with nodes. So every solution has its benefits and shortcomings, I guess.