draw humanoid using tikz graph
I am trying to make a similar plot using tikz libray in latex but so far I was only able to generate three humanoids. However, they are not scaled to fit properly in the plot and I can't place them correctly w.r.t. each other. Can anyone suggest how I can produce similar image:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, every node/.style={align=center}, tiny dot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=0.75pt}]

% Styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, minimum width=3.5em, minimum height=3.5em, text width=4em, align=center]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{humanoid} =[circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0.5pt]
% Function to draw humanoid graph
\newcommand{\drawhumanoid}[1]{
\begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
% Define nodes
\node[humanoid] (tophead) at (-0.15, 1) {};
\node[humanoid] (head) at (0, 0.9) {};
\node[humanoid] (neck) at (0, 0.75) {};
\node[humanoid] (shoulderL) at (-0.25, 0.75) {};
\node[humanoid] (shoulderR) at (0.25, 0.75) {};
\node[humanoid] (elbowL) at (-0.375, 0.375) {};
\node[humanoid] (elbowR) at (0.375, 0.45) {};
\node[humanoid] (wristL) at (-0.5, 0) {};
\node[humanoid] (wristR) at (0.5, 0.875) {};
\node[humanoid] (handL) at (-0.6, -0.075) {};
\node[humanoid] (handR) at (0.6, 0.95) {};
\node[humanoid] (hip) at (0, 0) {};
\node[humanoid] (thighL) at (-0.25, -0.5) {};
\node[humanoid] (thighR) at (0.25, -0.375) {};
\node[humanoid] (kneeL) at (-0.25, -0.875) {};
\node[humanoid] (kneeR) at (0.25, -0.75) {};
\node[humanoid] (footL) at (-0.25, -1.25) {};
\node[humanoid] (footR) at (0.25, -1.125) {};
\node[humanoid] (foot2L) at (-0.3, -1.325) {};
\node[humanoid] (foot2R) at (0.3, -1.05) {};

% Draw edges
\draw[edge] (tophead) -- (head);
\draw[edge] (head) -- (neck);
\draw[edge] (neck) -- (shoulderL);
\draw[edge] (neck) -- (shoulderR);
\draw[edge] (shoulderL) -- (elbowL);
\draw[edge] (shoulderR) -- (elbowR);
\draw[edge] (elbowL) -- (wristL);
\draw[edge] (elbowR) -- (wristR);
\draw[edge] (wristL) --(handL);
\draw[edge] (wristR) --(handR);
\draw[edge] (neck) -- (hip);
\draw[edge] (hip) -- (thighL);
\draw[edge] (hip) -- (thighR);
\draw[edge] (thighL) -- (kneeL);
\draw[edge] (thighR) -- (kneeR);
\draw[edge] (kneeL) -- (footL);
\draw[edge] (kneeR) -- (footR);
\draw[edge]  (footL) -- (foot2L);
\draw[edge]  (footR) -- (foot2R);
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\humanoid}[2]{
    % Head
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.15cm, minimum height=0.45cm, fill=orange!20,rotate=30] (head) at (#2) {};
    % Body
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.13cm, minimum height=1.1cm, fill=orange!20, below=0.05cm of head] (body) {};
    % Left upper arm
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.15cm, minimum height=0.8cm, fill=orange!20, left=0.05cm of body, rotate=340] (luarm) {};
    % Right upper arm
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.15cm, minimum height=0.8cm, fill=orange!20, right=0.1cm  of body, rotate=45] (ruarm) {};
    % Left lower arm
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, fill=orange!20, below=0.04cm of luarm,rotate=335] (llarm) {};
    % Right lower arm
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, fill=orange!20, below right=0.3cm of ruarm, rotate=140] (rlarm) {};
    % Left thigh
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.25cm, minimum height=0.95cm, fill=orange!20, below left=0.04cm of body,rotate=355] (lthigh) {};
    % Right thigh
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.25cm, minimum height=0.95cm, fill=orange!20, below right=0.04cm of body,rotate=20] (rthigh) {};
    % Left leg
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.15cm, minimum height=0.7cm, fill=orange!20, below=0.05cm of lthigh,rotate=345] (lleg) {};
    % Right leg
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.15cm, minimum height=0.7cm, fill=orange!20, below=0.05cm of rthigh, rotate=10] (rleg) {};
}

\newcommand{\sapient}[3]{
    % Head
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.25mm, minimum width=0.25cm, minimum height=0.45cm, fill=orange!20,rotate=30] (head) at (#2) {};
    % Body
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.125cm, minimum height=1.05cm, fill=orange!20, below=0.05cm of head] (body) {};
    % Left upper arm
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=0.9cm, fill=orange!20, left=0.05cm of body, rotate=340] (luarm) {};
    % Right upper arm
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.4cm, minimum height=0.75cm, fill=orange!20, right=0.15cm of body, rotate=45] (ruarm) {};
    % Left thigh
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.15cm, minimum height=1.325cm, fill=orange!20, below left=0.05cm  of body,rotate=355] (lthigh) {};
    % Right thigh
    \node[ellipse, draw=orange, line width=0.2mm, minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=1.325cm, fill=orange!20, below right=0.05cm of body,rotate=10] (rthigh) {};
}

% Nodes

\node (diff)[block] {Diff};
\node (multiscale) [block, right=2cm of diff,fill=orange!10,rotate=90] {Multiscale};

% Draw humanoid graphs for different scales
\drawhumanoid{($(multiscale.east) + (0.5, 1.5)$)};
\humanoid{($(multiscale.east) + (0.5, 0.0)$)};
\sapient{3}{5cm, -8cm}

\node (ms)[block, right=4cm of multiscale] {};

% Draw humanoid graph inside MGCU

\node (agg)[block, right=4cm of ms] {Weighted\\Sum};
\node (output)[block, right=2cm of agg] {Output};

% Arrows
\draw[arrow] (input) -- (diff);
\draw[arrow] (diff) -- (multiscale);

\draw [arrow] (multiscale) -- (head1);
\draw [arrow] (multiscale) -- (head2);
\draw [arrow] (multiscale) -- (head3);

\draw[arrow] (head1) -- ++(1,0) |- (ms);
\draw[arrow] (head2) -- ++(1,0) |- (ms);
\draw[arrow] (head3) -- ++(1,0) |- (ms);

\draw[arrow] (ms) -- (agg);
\draw[arrow] (agg) -- (output);

% Labels
\node[above=0.5cm of head1] {Encoder};

% Encapsulation boxes
\draw[dashed] (head1.north west) rectangle (lf3.south east);
\draw[dashed] (head4.north west) rectangle (rf4.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}    

Thanks.
Update:
I have generated images of skeletons (scale 3, scale 2 and scale 1 and two small skeletons under Diff node: here and here. How could I use tikz library to make a similar figure to the the attached picture now that I separately generated these images of skeletons?

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look for \tikzset in the tikz documentation instead.

Here is one way to do it, continuing the Inventive Principle of continued segmentation or fragmentation: it gives you more flexibility and control on the expense of more to control.
Assumptions
Your human image is stored as hum.png (bitmap), while the stacked graphic was compiled as humanoidsLinked.pdf (vector). // Don't hesitate to zoom into the .pdf from "1- Integrating ..." to see the difference.
1. Integrating separately drawn graphics
This approach was already described and linked here, "1. Changed strategy"

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    mlt/.style={draw,rotate=-90,fill=orange!20},
    hu/.style={draw=purple!80,rounded corners},
    >={Stealth},
 ]
    % ~~~ graphic elements ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[mlt]  (M)  at (0,0) {Multiscale};
    \node       (H2) at (1.5,0) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{hum}};
    \node[hu]   (HU) at (3.5,0) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{humanoidsLinked}};
    
    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (M)  -- (H2);
    \draw[->] (H2) -- (HU);
    \draw[->] (HU) -- +(1,0);;
    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=north] at (H2.south) {scale 2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

2. Creating the linked and stacked diagram
Some remarks.
Draw gray regions and links first, so that the humanoids will draw over it where needed. (Try moving said code to the end to see the difference.). Guess the starting point and relative movements needed, close the path. The first is a bit skewed, the other one rectangular, for demonstration purposes. Make you choice.
The skel can be drawn with its internal conenctions (c opc=1) or without. E.g. you can use the calculated coordinates to draw whatever is needed. Both opacities are lowered here on purpose. Unfortunately those coordinates aren't available "outside".
To define individual drawings via \skelhook you need to isolate them, e.g. by using a scope environment. Those can be placed absolutely (see the yshift).

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{skel}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ln/.style={draw=brown,line width=1.5pt},
    gr/.style={fill=gray!10,draw=none},
 ]
  % ~~~ gray regions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw[gr,draw=teal] (-2.5,- 2.5) -- ++(0.5,5.5) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(-.50,-5.5) -- cycle;
  \draw[gr] (-2,-8.5) -- ++(0,5.5) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,-5.5) -- cycle;

  % ~~~ links ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
  \draw[ln] (-1.5,0.5) -- (-.9,-4.6);
  \draw[ln] ( 1.4,0.4) -- ( .9,-4.6);

    % ~~~ some humanoids ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{scope}   % isolate this scope (i.e.: \skelhook)
    \newcommand{\skelhook}{
        \foreach \c in {N,U,MHR,MHL,MFR,MFL,HPR,HPL}
            \draw[fill=yellow] (\c) circle[radius=1mm];     
    }
        \skel{o ularm=210,o lrarm=320,c opc=.3}
    \end{scope}     
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm] % isolate, see above
    \newcommand{\skelhook}{
        \foreach \c in {U,M,ER,EL,KL,KR}{
            \draw[fill=blue] (\c) circle[radius=.5mm];
            \draw[blue] (M) -- (\c);
        }   
    }
        \skel{o urleg=310,c opc=.2}
    \end{scope}     
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Here's one way to do it.
1. Changed strategy
Instead of drawing all in one big file, I suggest to

draw and compile each humanoid separately with standalone
include those .pdf's in your main document via package graphicx
which allows also for \node ... {\includegraphics{..}};
this approach resolves most of the scaling problems, leaving good selection of diameters etc. as the real challange ...

See here for a similar example.
2. Put this file in your drawing directory
Name it skel.sty . I may or may not provide it as a package in future. Basic ideas:

specify length of limbs and their absolute orientations
calculate coordinates from these parameters/options
skel outputs a skeleton like a sticky diagram
write a skelhook macro to add more to it

For the hook see cfr's anser here. What happens is that skel first outputs a \pic, and, if defined somewhere, whatever you wrote into the skelhook. Coordinates are available, before skel leaves its scope.
\tikzset{
skel/.search also={/tikz,/pgf}, % i.e. allow standard options
skel/.cd,
l neck/.initial=.7,
l spine/.initial=2,
l should/.initial=.8,
l uarm/.initial=.8,
l larm/.initial=.8,
l mh/.initial=.3, % middle hand
l hip/.initial=.5,
l uleg/.initial=1,
l lleg/.initial=1,
l mf/.initial=0.1, % middle foot
o lshould/.initial=180,
o rshould/.initial=0,
o ularm/.initial=-90,
o llarm/.initial=-90,
o urarm/.initial=-90,
o lrarm/.initial=-90,
o lmh/.initial=270, % middle hand
o rmh/.initial=270, % middle hand
o hip/.initial=0,
o ulleg/.initial=-90,
o llleg/.initial=-90,
o urleg/.initial=-90,
o lrleg/.initial=-90,
o lmf/.initial=270, % middle foot
o rmf/.initial=270, % middle foot
c clr/.initial=black,
c opc/.initial=1,
}
\def\pv#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/skel/#1}}
\newcommand\skel[1]{
 \begin{scope}[
  dr/.style={draw=\pv{c clr}, draw opacity=\pv{c opc}},
  skel/.pic={
  % ~~~ HIP ~~~
  \draw[dr]  (\pv{o hip}:-\pv{l hip}) coordinate (HPL)
  -- (\pv{o hip}: \pv{l hip}) coordinate (HPR);
  \coordinate (M) (0,0); 
  % ~~~ LEGS ~~~~~
  \draw[dr] (HPL) -- +(\pv{o ulleg}:\pv{l uleg}) coordinate (KL);
  \draw[dr] (KL) -- +(\pv{o llleg}:\pv{l lleg}) coordinate (FL);
  \draw[dr] (FL) -- +(\pv{o lmf}:\pv{l mf}) coordinate (MFL);
  %
  \draw[dr] (HPR) -- +(\pv{o urleg}:\pv{l uleg}) coordinate (KR);
  \draw[dr] (KR) -- +(\pv{o lrleg}:\pv{l lleg}) coordinate (FR);
  \draw[dr] (FR) -- +(\pv{o rmf}:\pv{l mf}) coordinate (MFR);
  % ~~~ SPINE ~~~~
  \draw[dr] (0,0) coordinate (M) -- +(0,\pv{l spine}) coordinate (U);
  % ~~~ SHOULDER ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw[dr] (U) -- +(\pv{o rshould}:\pv{l should}) coordinate (SR);
  \draw[dr] (U) -- +(\pv{o lshould}:\pv{l should}) coordinate (SL);
  % ~~~ ARMS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw[dr] (SL) -- +(\pv{o ularm}:\pv{l uarm}) coordinate (EL); 
  \draw[dr] (EL) -- +(\pv{o llarm}:\pv{l larm}) coordinate (HL);
  \draw[dr] (HL) -- +(\pv{o lmh}:\pv{l mh}) coordinate (MHL);
  \draw[dr] (SR) -- +(\pv{o urarm}:\pv{l uarm}) coordinate (ER);
  \draw[dr] (ER) -- +(\pv{o lrarm}:\pv{l larm}) coordinate (HR);
  \draw[dr] (HR) -- +(\pv{o rmh}:\pv{l mh}) coordinate (MHR);
  % ~~~ NECK ~~~
  \draw[dr] (U) -- +(0,\pv{l neck}) coordinate (N); 
  },
]
\tikzset{skel/.cd,#1} 
\pic {skel};
\ifcsname skelhook\endcsname\skelhook\fi
 \end{scope}
}

Introducing middle hand and foot was necessary to account for relevant birds anatomy: our hands and feet evolved into their last wing and what we'd call lower leg. (Also birds don't really have a shoulder, but you can mimick that by using short limbs and steep angles.) If you don't need them, set their lengths to zero.
It's intended to be a 2D sketch. So if you want to give a 3D-illusion, adjust lengths and orientations as needed. (You'd also draw parallelograms instead of a square for the blue thingies in the grayish areas, anticipating perspective.)
3. Your humanoids
To draw your various humanoids

provide macro \skelhook (one per tikzpicture environment)
adjust parameters

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{skel}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    greenish/.style={teal,fill=teal!30},
 ]
    \newcommand\skelhook[0]{
        \draw[orange,fill=yellow] (SL) to [bend left=90] (EL) to [bend left=90] (SL);
        \draw[greenish] (EL) to [bend left] (HL) to [bend left] (EL);
        \foreach \c in {N,MHR,MHL,MFR,MFL,SR,HPR,HPL,HR,HL,ER}
            \draw[fill=yellow] (\c) circle[radius=.5mm,];
    }
    \skel{o ularm=250,o llarm=300,  % parts of left arm
          o hip=10,                 % rigid hip
%         l hip=0,                  % try it
          c clr=purple,c opc=.3}    % color & opacity
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

To adjust color and opacity of the skel use options c clr=purple,c opc=.3} % color & opacity.
Define styles as usual, e.g. via
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
        greenish/.style={teal,fill=teal!30},
     ]

To put circles use the coordinates, like so:
        \foreach \c in {N,MHR,MHL,MFR,MFL,SR,HPR,HPL,HR,HL,ER}
            \draw[fill=yellow] (\c) circle[radius=.5mm,];

AFAIK rotated ellipses are not well provided by Tikz. So a bypass may be using extreme bending, like so:
        \draw[orange,fill=yellow] (SL) to [bend left=90] (EL) to [bend left=90] (SL);



Thanks for your reply. It is more general than mine but I am wondering how I could put together all these pieces and make a plot similar to the one attached to my question? I made the small pictures as you suggested. My main concern was how they can be integrated in this figure together.

Thank you. // See my first remark. Draw about seven individual humanoid (as .pdf). Use \node .. {\includegraphics{}}; to draw and place them. In other words: delete all humanoids for the moment from both image and your mind. What’s left, is easy to draw. Then put said nodes. That‘s all. // BTW, marking code in covmments on an iPad is … … …

Here is a node based example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647401/245790 . Should be a low-brainer now ;-)

Well my main issue is that node with three sheets and nodes connected inside and between sheets.

Please see my other answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721206/245790 . I suggest to look up commands in parallel in the tikz manual, e.g. at https://tikz.dev/ .
